# How can I capture the stdin and stdout of system command from a Perl script?

Tags: perl, ipc

In the middle of a Perl script, there is a system command I want to execute. I have a string that contains the data that needs to be fed into stdin (the command only accepts input from stdin), and I need to capture the output written to stdout. I've looked at the various methods of executing system commands in Perl, and the `open` function seems to be what I need, except that it looks like I can only capture stdin or stdout, not both.

At the moment, it seems like my best solution is to use `open`, redirect stdout into a temporary file, and read from the file after the command finishes. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to take a look at [IPC::Open2](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0/lib/IPC/Open2.pm)

Answer (score 6):

IPC::Open2/3 are fine, but I've found that usually all I really need is [IPC::Run3](http://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3), which handles the simple cases really well with minimal complexity:

```
use IPC::Run3;    # Exports run3() by default

run3( \@cmd, \$in, \$out, \$err );
```

The documentation compares IPC::Run3 to other alternatives.  It's worth a read even if you don't decide to use it.

Answer (score 3):

IPC::Open3 would probably do what you want. It can capture STDERR and STDOUT.

http://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere at the top of your script, include the line

```
use IPC::Open2;
```

That will include the necessary module, usually installed with most Perl distributions by default.  (If you don't have it, you could install it using CPAN.)  Then, instead of open, call:

```
$pid = open2($cmd_out, $cmd_in, 'some cmd and args');
```

You can send data to your command by sending it to $cmd_in and then read your command's output by reading from $cmd_out.

If you also want to be able to read the command's stderr stream, you can use the IPC::Open3 module instead.

Comment: To anyone reading this, you should make sure and not use bareword filehandles as this example does.  See this doc: http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?bareword_uppercase_filehandles

Answer (score 3):

The [perlipc documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) covers many ways that you can do this, including IPC::Open2 and IPC::Open3.

Answer (score 2):

A very easy way to do this that I recently found is **the [IPC::Filter](http://p3rl.org/IPC::Filter) module**. It lets you do the job extremely intuitively:

```
$output = filter $input, 'somecmd', '--with', 'various=args', '--etc';
```

Note how it invokes your command without going through the shell if you pass it a list. It also does a reasonable job of handling errors for common utilities. (On failure, it `die`s, using the text from STDERR as its error message; on success, STDERR is just discarded.)

Of course, it’s not suitable for huge amounts of data since it provides no way of doing any streaming processing; also, the error handling might not be granular enough for your needs. But it makes the many simple cases really *really* simple.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special perl command for it

```
open2()
```

More info can be found on: http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Misc/perl-5.6.1/lib/IPC/Open2.html

Comment: Dude, why do you post something that has already been posted?

Answer (score 0):

I always do it this way if I'm only expecting a single line of output or want to split the result on something other than a newline:

```
my $result = qx( command args 2>&1 );  
my $rc=$?;  
# $rc >> 8 is the exit code of the called program.

if ($rc != 0 ) {  
    error();  
}
```

If you want to deal with a multi-line response, get the result as an array:

```
my @lines = qx( command args 2>&1 );  

foreach ( my $line ) (@lines) {  
    if ( $line =~ /some pattern/ ) {  
        do_something();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: i don't see where your example handles STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to include extra packages, you can just do

```
open(TMP,">tmpfile");
print TMP  $tmpdata ;
open(RES,"$yourcommand|");
$res = "" ;
while(<RES>){
$res .= $_ ;
}
```

which is the contrary of what you suggested, but should work also.